# iPhone Safari html inputs doesn't work

Tags: html, iphone, mobile, input, responsive

I have a Landing page with a regular form on it and on iPhone 5 and 7 the Input[type="text"] and checkbox aren't clickable. I'm sorry but it's a corporate LP that i can't share.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you at least post the code? or make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
input, textarea {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -khtml-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it didn't work.